# DNS my A Record - getting Content from my Subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain

help would be much appreciated

Problem:

I registered a new Domain, which I want to run as a News Site...

Domain is all ready Live now incl. SSL   here : news24.studio

I have a SaaS based Software, which I bought and setup a Subdomain which is running on WP and has the whole Feeds and Features included getting all my News. So all Content for the News is created in the Subdomain which I now want to show in my other Site  news24.studio

So, I setup the IP in the DNS of news24.studio  with the IP of the SubDomain

which should show now the Content of the Subdomain in my news24.studio

here this sub Domain  :   news24.buzzpresscloud.com

But it is not coming in / showing .... driving me crazy .... anybody knows Why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will likely run into multiple issues resolving this - including https cert issues.

I believe the answer to your problem is likely a misunderstanding between DNS and HTTP. DNS us useful in resolving a domain to a given IP address, however most web servers have multiple different websites all sharing the same IP address. Modern versions of the http and https protocol send the domain name to the web server as a header (and as part of https negotiation) - and the server needs to recognise the domain name and direct it to the appropriate config.  It appears this is not configured for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer here. The Instruction was simple by the News Provider were I had setup the subdomain - news24.buzzpresscloud.com - which told me to setup an  - A Record in the DNS pointing to their Domain - which I did - so after propagating the pointed IP when I went onto the Subdomain it pulled up my - news24.studio -  which is what we want.... but the Content from the Subdomain is not coming in.... that is the only Problem ..... checked with Namecheap Support and they did not know why its not coming in... because it is all correct... so maybe it is the -  .htaccess ?

Comment: Then this is not a DBS issue.